# The Flowers Riled Her... But the Stranger's Wilder

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, knowledge, poetry

I was away on school camp for three days — but I am back now, catching up on what I missed out on, as well as giving you what you missed out on, too.

> My prefix is basic ending all that it sees.
>
> My suffix has ethics, when it quietly agrees.
>
> My infix has questions, but no answers, it seems.
>
> With red, I have strawberries and wine for sweet dreams.

This might be a *little* hard, so I'll give a hint tomorrow... unless I already have. (And funnily enough, the riddle has a *red* herring $\ast$badum chhhh$\ast$).

Also, what could the title be referring to? (Excuse the other pun.)

---

**Hint:**

> **PREFIX**: Do you see what *I see*? 
>  **SUFFIX**: *Yes*, but *shhh*! 
>  **INFIX**: Umm... *what do you see?* 
>  **RED**: Well, I see a cottage amid the greenwood!

Comment: "With red" herring?

Comment: are the two italic words supposed to be a clue?

Comment: @ShahriarMahmudSajid yes. What is something you might know of that has the italic words? :P

Comment: @Duck indeed. (ROT13) "Erq" zvtug abg ersre gb jung lbh svefg gubhtug...

Comment: Rot13(yvggyr erq evqvat ubbq) comes to mind obviously :P

Comment: @ShahriarMahmudSajid which is why it is not in the riddle, but instead it is in italics and a bit more subtle... the answer is found in the story of your Rot13 comment :P **Edit:** I should probably write this very comment in Rot13, but ah well :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Answer is probably-

> Basket

Prefix-

> Bas (basic minus the ic, *i see*)

Infix-

> ask, asking a question doesn't always get an answer.

Suffix-

> probably et, as ethics start with et, and as explained by OP the quietly agree part is explained by ic(i see) and sh (shh keep quiet) that can be found in the spelling, cool wordplay.

Last line and title explanation-

> it refers to the story of little red riding hood as I've said in a comment, she went through a forest to her grandma's house, as told in the hint as well, saw some lovely flowers that she liked, and met a wild stranger i.e. the wolf. Also she carried a basket with her, hence the story reference.

Comment: Yes! You got it! DVL12 so I can't upvote now, but when would you like the tick? **Edit:** Oh, forgot to mention, (ROT13) Gur jbeq "rguvpf" unf "fu" naq "vp" va vg :D

Comment: is the suffix correct? wasn't sure on that one, you can give the tick anytime, no worries.

Comment: Yes, it is. My Rot13 comment should hint out the explanation for that :P

Comment: just saw that edit, nice one.

Comment: Oh, woops, forgot to give the tick. Congratulations! Seriously, please remind me to give a tick if an entire $24$ hours have passed and I didn't. $\color{green}{\checkmark}$

Comment: no worries mate, i was hoping this question would get some more views, it was such a nice one.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any advice that you can give to make my riddles better? (None of us are perfect.)

Comment: i've always liked your riddles, even when i couldn't figure them out. They have a good flow and makes you think. just keep them coming..

Comment: Alright. I have had people telling me I should try and send them to a local newspaper or something along those lines, but I want to wait it out, become better at making my riddles, and then when I first send one in (because I will!) I'll ensure that it is completely polished. Do you think I am making a right decision? (I ask you because if that is you in your profile picture, then you are older than me and most likely have more experience.)

Comment: i think that is a wise call, make some more puzzles, then polish your best ones to send, and BTW it actually is me in the pic, but not sure how old you guessed though :D

Comment: Hahah, no I'm not saying you are *old*. I am saying that I am young. I am just a normal kid, going to a normal school, who has some... not so normal interests... at least amongst the kids in my class. Idk, I am guessing your $26$ max :P

Comment: good guess, on point.

Comment: xD ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

> Appointment

My prefix is basic ending all that it sees.

> Appoint - a point, or a dot, or a period, ends most sentences.

My infix has questions, but no answers, it seems.

> me - the OP, brings the question and not answers

My suffix has ethics, when it quietly agrees.

> Ent? It's a species of trees from the Lord of the Rings that are quite nice people (tree people), they're ethical and very quiet. Most of them don't talk, or do so very slowly.

I'm not very confident about the infix and the suffix, but maybe the infix is a good try and I'll figure out the rest later.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not the correct answer. I will write out a hint :P